# How to sort integer array in golang using default sort function

Tags: sorting, go

A stupid question. I can't sort using default sort function in go

```golang
package main
import "fmt"
import "sort"

func main() {
    var arr [5]int
    fmt.Println("Enter 5 elements")
    for i:=0;i<5;i++{
        fmt.Scanf("%d",&arr[i])
    }
    sort.Ints(arr)
    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

When executing the above program, It throws out

```
cannot use arr (type [5]int) as type []int in argument to sort.Ints
```

Need Help.

Comment: `sort.Ints` takes a slice, not an array.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sort.Ints` expects a slice of int, not an array.  Easiest fix is to change

```
sort.Ints(arr)
```

to

```
sort.Ints(arr[:])
```

Comment: What change is arr[:] actually making?

Comment: @JoseThomas: read over this https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals.

Comment: What is the complexity of this default sort function?

Comment: There is no "default sort function" as far as sorting algorithm used.  Go uses different algorithms based on some criteria.  You can read through them in the comments or by following along the code here: https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go